# RxJava. Initial onNext when subscription starts?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to implement a class that emits changes using an Observable.
When a subscription is done to this observable I want to send an starting/initialization event. Then I want to send the usual events.

For example. Lets say I have two different subscribers A and B. A and B starts subscribing at different times. If MyClass.getChanges() emits event no. 1,2,3,4 and 5.

If A starts it subscription between event 1,2 then it should receive the following events:
InitialEvent, 2, 3, 4, 5.

If B starts it subscription between event 4 and 5, then B should receive the following events:
InitialEvent, 5.

How to do this using RxJava?

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

I think I need to explain that the "InitialEvent" is different each time it's emitted. It's calculated by MyClass each time a new subscriber starts to subscribe from getChanged().

My scenario is that MyClass contains a list. The "initialEvent" contains the list at the moment when the subscription is done. Then each change to this list is emitted from getChanges().

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post this 2 years later, but I had the same need and found this question unanswered.

What I did is the following:

```
public Observable<Event> observe() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> 
        subject.startWith(createInitialEvent())
    );
}
```

The idea is the following:

- defer() executes the passed-in lambda expression when an observer subscribes to the Observable returned by the method observe(). So basically, it executes subject.startWith(...), which returns an Observable that is the actual source of event for the subscriber.
- subject.startWith(...) emits an initial event (specified by startWith(...)) followed by those emitted by the subject.

So, if I come back to the original post:
if an observer starts it subscription between event 1,2 then it should receive the following events: InitialEvent, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`PublishSubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject#publishsubject). Subjects are hot `Observables`, in that they do not wait for `Observers` to `subscribe` to them before beginning to emit their items.  Here's a bit of info on [Subjects](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject).

Here's a quick demo of your use-case

```
    PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    Observable<String> InitEvent = Observable.just("init");
    Observable<String> A = subject.asObservable();
    Observable<String> B = subject.asObservable();

    subject.onNext("1");

    A.startWith(InitEvent)
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("A: " + s));

    subject.onNext("2");
    subject.onNext("3");
    subject.onNext("4");

    B.startWith(InitEvent)
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("B: " + s));

    subject.onNext("5");
```

Comment: Thank you. But neither A nor B is getting an "initial event" here. The output should be: A: init, A: 2, A: 3, A: 4, B: Init, A: 5, B: 5.

Comment: Hey @ErikZ I've added an extra Observable which is used with `startWith` on A & B. The results are now as you've shown in your comment. Those this work better for you?

Comment: almost there. :) See my edit of my question. The initial event need to be calculated inside my class MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not really elegant way how about just using a flag? It looks like you just want to replace the first emitted event.

e.g. for one subscription the following logic:

```
boolean firstTimeA = true;

myCustomObservable.subscribe(s -> {
   System.out.println(firstTimeA ? "initEvent" : s.toString());
   if(firstTimeA) firstTimeA = false;
});
```

And since you want to have a second subscription just create a `firstTimeB` and update it your B subscription.

Comment: Thank you. See my edit of my question. The initial event must be calculated inside MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking something like this should work for you

```
int last = 0;
Observable obs;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

public SimpleListObservable() {
    obs = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
            while(last < 30) {
                last++;
                list.add(last);
                subscriber.onNext(last);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}

public Observable<Integer> process() {
    return Observable.from(list).concatWith(obs);
}
```

As the source observable collects values they are added to the `List` (you can transform the items as you see fit, filter them out, etc) and then when `ObserverB` subscribes it will get a replay of the items already collected in the `List` before continuing with the source observable output.

This simple test should demonstrate the outcome

```
public void testSequenceNext() {
    final SimpleListObservable obs = new SimpleListObservable();

    final Observer<Integer> ob2 = Mockito.mock(Observer.class);

    obs.process().subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            ob1Complete = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println("ob1: " + integer);
            if (integer == 20) {
                obs.process().subscribe(ob2);
            }
        }
    });

    ArgumentCaptor<Integer> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);

    Mockito.verify(ob2, Mockito.times(30)).onNext(captor.capture());

    for (Integer value : captor.getAllValues()) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this, I've made part of my API of course as I'm on a phone :

```
public class StreamOfSomething {
    new StreamOfSomething() {
        // source of events like
        events = Observable.range(0, 1_000_000_000)
                           .doOnNext(set::add) // some operation there
                           .map(Event::change)
                           .publish()
                           .refCount();
    }

    public Observable<Event> observeChanges() {
        return events.startWith(
                 Observable.just(Event.snapshot(set))); // start stream with generated event
    }
}
```

And the client can do something like :

```
Observable.timer(2, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .limit(2)
          .flatMap(t -> theSourceToWatch.observeChanges().limit(10))
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Note however if you are in a multithreaded environment you may have to synchronize when you are subscribing to block any modification, otherwise the list may change before it get's emitted. Or rework this class completely around observables, I don't know yet how to achieve this though.